# How do I compile multiple CSS file into a zip/tar file and include them in the HTML page markup?

Tags: html, css

I have many CSS files on hand and google webmaster tools and google webmaster tools recommends compiling them.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You probably want gzip compression rather than a zip/tar file. Gzip compression is a server setting (usually in a .htaccess file on Apache servers). You might want to have a look at the .htaccess included in HTML5 Boilerplate https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what technologies are available to you, you might want to take a look at something like [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) to combine multiple CSS/JS files into one. This saves on HTTP requests, making page loads slightly quicker.

I'm not sure if there is a tool out there that combines the contents of a .zip/.tar file; it's likely that you'll have to write your own if that's the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe they mean you should write the content of the many css-files into a fewer number of css-files instead of compiling or packing them in an archive-like file (which a browser cant read) ...
and i agree: lesser requests helps loading your site faster
it's faster to load one 10kb-file instead of ten 1kb-files